# Close Bootstrap popover on esc keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to close bootstrap popover using <kbd>ESC</kbd> key press.

But it does not seem to be working when using:

```js
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 27) {
        $('#example').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle with bootstrap popover:

http://jsfiddle.net/mashinista/b2NKt/

Comment: Code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/b2NKt/1/

Comment: thanks, must have missed something

Comment: Interestingly, the [modal plugin has a keyboard option](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) which is true by default and automatically `closes the modal when escape key is pressed`.  That would be a nice feature for the popover as well.

Comment: @KyleMit Relevant: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11269

Answer (score 6):

The fiddle you included has the popover code, but not the escape code.

Add it and, as koala_dev pointed out, you should be fine:

#### [Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2NKt/3/)

```js
$('#example').popover();

$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 27) {
        $('#example').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Also, this is very similar to how the [modal escape function works](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L136)

Comment: Works well with bootstrap4 too. https://jsfiddle.net/mark_iv/dzvgsqt3/2/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that arises when a tooltip is inside of a modal, because then the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is expected to close the modal. It's a not good user experience if a user only wants to dismiss the tooltip but then the entire modal closes. So I would propose, if there are currently tooltips to dismiss, then a user will need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice to close the modal (first time to dismiss tooltips), but otherwise once, as usually. Note: This is not ideal, especially for screen reader users, so take that as a food for the further thinking.

```js
/**
 * Accessibility: Close tooltips and popovers on ESC key (WCAG 1.4.13)
 * Note: Using event capture:true to cancel the propagation preventing the modal to close at first (hence no `.on()` here)
 * Tested with Bootstrap v3.4.1; Does not support IE 11
 */
$.fn.listenEscKeyToCloseOverlays = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (("undefined" !== typeof $.fn.tooltip) || ("undefined" !== typeof $.fn.popover)) {
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                if ('Escape' === e.key) {
                    const $openTooltips = $('.tooltip');
                    const $openPopovers = $('.popover');

                    if ($openPopovers.length || $openTooltips.length) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $openTooltips.tooltip('hide');
                        $openPopovers.popover('hide');
                    }
                }
            }, true);
        }
    });
};

$(document).listenEscKeyToCloseOverlays();
```