# Angular-strap close popover when clicking ESC from keyboard

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using [Angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers), auto-close directive close the popover when clicking outside of it, what about ESC button ? how can i close the popover when ESC button clicked from keyboard ?

Comment: A code sample would be helpful here.  For the record, someone else has reported this as an issue:

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1537

Answer (score 1):

Here's another SO question that's related to your question though it uses a jQuery approach which you may need to integrate into your app:

[Close Bootstrap popover on esc keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659976/close-bootstrap-popover-on-esc-keypress)

Here's the demo: [Plunker demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2NKt/3/)

Here's the jQuery approach:

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which === 27) {
        $('#example').popover('hide');
    }
});
```